# Error in Gradle Build App level when adding firebase UI

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, firebaseui

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jVXV.png)

How can I add Firebase UI dependency? I'm not sure which version is compatible with my sdk version 26.

Comment: what is your error?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at release notes for `FirebaseUI` i.e. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases

It contains following (for latest version...3.0)

```
This version has the following notable transitive dependencies:

    Firebase / Play services 11.4.2
    Support Library 26.1.0
    Facebook SDK 4.27
```

In general you can run something like following to list transitive dependencies that exist in your build.

```
./gradlew -q dependencies <your_module>:dependencies
```